# Reading a single csv file from s3 bucket using amazon athena and querying it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Basically I want a SQL connection to a csv file in a s3 bucket using Amazon Athena. I also do not know any information other than that the first row will give the names of the headers. Does anyone know any solution to this?

Comment: Could you please post any solutions you have attempted so far?

Comment: @party-ring I've checked this guys Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcFFOyYEWKc&t=165s but he only explains that the file must be within a folder AND that you must pass in the parameters for creating the table and do some fixup query after that. I was wondering like is there an easy way to do this, where we originally do not know what the parameters are and can access the csv file directly instead of having to put it through a folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two ways of doing this. One is to examine a few rows of the file to detect the data types, then create a `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement as seen at the [Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html).

If you know you are getting only strings and numbers (for example) and if you know all the columns will have values, it can be relatively easy to build it that way. But if types can be more flexible or columns can be empty, building a robust solution from scratch might be tricky.

So the second option would be to use the AWS Glue Catalog to [define a crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html), which does exactly what I told you above, but automatically. It also creates the metadata you need in Athena, so you don't need to write the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

As a bonus, you can use that automatically catalogued data not only from Athena, but also from Redshift and EMR. And if you keep adding new files to the same bucket (every day, every hour, every week...) you can tell the crawl to pass again and rediscover the data in case the schema has evolved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Javier! It makes sense to me, I just need more clarification though, would I be correct to say that: Athena only works well IF you know the metadata beforehand AND you store the csv file within a folder cause it seems to me that Athena only works only on those conditions

Comment: You are correct on both accounts. Athena works with data for which the schema is known. You can use AWS Glue to discover and catalog the data, or do it by hand. But in the end the table needs to be defined and have a schema. Also, Athena works only with data on S3. It doesn't need to be CSV (other formats like parquet are more efficient), but whatever the format, the data needs to live in a bucket, which is the name Amazon S3 uses for the concept of a parent folder

Comment: Note that Athena reads all files within an S3 prefix. A prefix is similar to a folder on a normal filesystem.
For example, if you had the bucket `mybucket` and the prefix `data/csv/`, the full S3 location would be `s3://mybucket/data/csv/`.
If you created a table using that S3 location, Athena will scan all objects within it when executing a query. That would also include files within "subfolders", such as `data/csv/one/` and `data/csv/two/`.
[Athena docs on table locations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html)